# Disabling Back button on the browser

Tags: browser, back-button

I am writing an application that if the user hits back, it may resend the same information and mess up the flow and integrity of data. How do I disable it for users who are with and without javascript on?

Comment: If i'm using your site, the back button is still MINE. Do not mess with what's mine... ;-)

Comment: This is the wrong question.  What you should do is design the application such that when the information is resent, the application will recognize it and act appropriately.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It's not possible, sadly. However, consider your applications navigation model. Are you using Post/Redirect/Get PRG Model? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get?

This model is more back button friendly than the Postback model.

Comment: Nothing sad about it.

Comment: Valid point. I'm just sad. ;)

Comment: Scott - Is the ability to disable the toolbars and right click menu IE specific then?  I've seen LOB apps that completely lock down the navigation, but (again sadly) they also require the user have IE.

Comment: Well, some apps can run themselves in "Kiosk" mode, but that involves launch IE with command line switches.

Comment: @Jess: That's one of those annoyances that good browsers try to fix, like unrequested pop-up windows. Firefox got a "Disable or replace context menu" setting for this reason.

Comment: Is it possible to put confirmation question before back button lead us to the previous page? In case OK go previous if cancel stay where you are.

Comment: 1. Code your web app using AJAX only, do not change the URL at all.
2. Handle onbeforeunload to warn that they are about to leave the app.
This also prevents leaking information to the browser history (and you might also want to disable caching). It would be too much work to make this change to an existing app; this approach is only feasible if you build your app in this way from the beginning.

Answer (score 12):

You shouldn't.

You could attach some script to the onbeforeunload event of a page and confirm with the user that's what they want to do; and you can go a bit further and *try* to [disable it](http://www.irt.org/script/311.htm) but of course that will only work for users who have javascript turned on. Instead look at rewriting the app so you don't commit transactions on each page submit, but only at the end of the process.

Comment: Hmmm... the onbeforeunload event would be called also when navigating away from the page because user is simply going to another page (not only because user pushed the back button), and the script would be called.

Answer (score 8):

I strongly urge you to go to heroic lengths to prevent breaking the back button, it is a sure fire way to alienate your users and even made it to No.1 on [Jacob Neilsen's Top 10 Web Design Mistakes in 1999](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/990530.html).

Perhaps you could consider rather asking the question: "How to avoid breaking the back button for <insert your scenario here>?"

If Scott's answer hits close to the mark, consider changing your flow to the PRG model.  If it's something else, then give a bit more detail and see how we can help.

Comment: He did not say he wanted to "break" the back button. He wants to avoid a common pitfall where modern Ajax design patterns fail because a user presses "Back" meaning "Undo The Thing I Just Did With Your Ajax App" and instead gets "Go Back One Arbitrary And Ambiguous HTTP Request".

Comment: To me that just reads "he didn't want to break the back button, he just wanted to break the back button to prevent it being broken".  :S

It is possible to get AJAX/JavaScript and back buttons to play nice, all I'm suggesting is that would be the route I'd recommend following.

Answer (score 7):

I came up with a little hack that disables the back button using JavaScript. I checked it on chrome 10, firefox 3.6 and IE9:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<script type = "text/javascript" >
function changeHashOnLoad() {
     window.location.href += "#";
     setTimeout("changeHashAgain()", "50"); 
}

function changeHashAgain() {
  window.location.href += "1";
}

var storedHash = window.location.hash;
window.setInterval(function () {
    if (window.location.hash != storedHash) {
         window.location.hash = storedHash;
    }
}, 50);


</script>
</head>
<body onload="changeHashOnLoad(); ">
Try to hit back!
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But it works - go ahead and test it.

Comment: I don't doubt that. It's just a bad experience for the user, who may actually *want* to go back.

Comment: IE9 doesn't allow me to scroll down for this one. Works fine in  latest FF, Chrome, Safari. The people that will use my single page app will only have IE<=9 to use though.

Comment: Its not always a bad experience for the user, sometimes its the right experience. for example, a page may change its state with Ajax, e.g. gmail. when the user clicks 'back', the user actually expects the page to go back to the previous *state*, rather than to go back to the previous *page*

Comment: Whilst not terribly nice, this solution is perfect for a specific application I am working on and it works nicely.
Is there a reason why IE9 has issues though? When scrolling down it keeps jumping back to the top of the page.
Any solution for our IE9 users?

Comment: It uses HTML anchors to disable the back button, so that when the user clicks back he's actually jumping to the previous anchor. in this case, '#1' or '#'. if they don't exist in the page, the page will scroll to the top. It can be fixed with other anchor texts or with javascript

Answer (score 5):

Best option is not to depend on postbacks to control flow, however if you are stuck with it (for now)

you may use something like this:

```
  Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
  Response.Cache.SetExpires(Now.AddSeconds(-1));
  Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
  Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

Soon you will find that it will not work on all browsers, but then you may introduce a check in your code like:

```
 if (Page.IsPostBack)
 {
        if (pageIsExpired()){
           Response.Redirect("/Some_error_page.htm");
        }
        else {
           var now = Now;
           Session("TimeStamp") = now.ToString();
           ViewState("TimeStamp") = now.ToString();
        }

  private boolean pageIsExpired()
  {
     if (Session("TimeStamp") == null || ViewState("TimeStamp") == null)
        return false;

     if (Session("TimeStamp") == ViewState("TimeStamp"))
        return true;

        return false;
  }
```

That will solve problem to some extend, Code not checked -- only for examples purposes..

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to disable back button in all major browser. It just uses hash values to disable the back button completely.
Just put these 5 lines of code in your page

```
 <script>
window.location.hash="no-back-button";
window.location.hash="Again-no-back-button";//for google chrome
window.onhashchange=function(){window.location.hash="no-back-button";}
</script>
```

[**Detailed description**](http://programmerslate.blogspot.in/2013/06/disable-back-button-of-your-browser.html)

Comment: Tricky one..but works...

Comment: doesn't work correctly in all cases, namely chrome, safari.

Comment: Please don't do this! It's really annoying if pages mess with basic browser functionality.

Comment: I completely understand I just answered it to answer the asked question, it is up to the reader to decide whether it's good or not

Answer (score 3):

Here's a previous post on it:
[Prevent Use of the Back Button (in IE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54539/prevent-use-of-the-back-button-in-ie)

Comment: well, the recommendation engine didn't show it as I created the post :(

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you come up with to disable the back button might not stop the back button in future browsers.

If its late in the development cycle I suggest you try some suggestions above but when you get time you should structure your flow so that the back button does not interfere with the logic of your site, it simply takes the user back to the previous page like they expect it to do.

Answer (score 1):

It is true, proper validation should be added to make sure duplicate data doesn't mess things up. However, as in my case, I don't full control of the data since I'm using some third party API after my form. So I  used this

```
history.go(+1);
```

This will send user forward to the "receipt" which is supposed to come after "payment" page if they try to go back to "payment" page (just giving a payment for example). Use sparingly, though

Answer (score 0):

You could post the data on each form to a _NEW window.  This will disable the back button on each window, but without javascript it might be difficult to force the old one closed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by using:

```
 Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.MinValue);
 Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

When I used Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache); it prevented me from downloading office files.

Answer (score 0):

Find below link

Disable browser back button functionality using JavaScript in asp.net | ASP.Net disable browser back button (using javascript)

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/11/disable-browser-back-button.html