# ASP.NET after form submission reload a fresh version of the exact same page

Tags: asp.net

I'm doing a form submission on my ASP.NET page. After the user has pressed submit I want them to have a completely fresh version of the page so that they cant press reload and resubmit and so its a completely clean start.

I gather that `Server.Transfer()` is bad, I know I could maybe post a random string in the URL. But is there a better way?

---

#### See also:

> - [Disabling Back button on the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87422/disabling-back-button-on-the-browser)

Answer (score 3):

See the [POST-REDIRECT-GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. There is no need to add random query strings.