# after login not use back button for going privious page

Tags: asp.net

I am working in ASP.NET and would like to restrict the back button after someone logs into my application.  I have a login page and I don't want the user to go back to the previous page when they click the back button.

Comment: "send me the codez" isn't going to get you any help here.

Comment: I'm guessing English is not your first language (or is it?) but using "text speak" doesn't help the readability of your question.

Comment: Proper English seems to be very overrated nowadays.. +1 for @Marc

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921230/redirect-back-to-a-page-after-a-login and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562020/restricting-the-use-of-back-button-without-javascript

Comment: @Tony , impossible. That's written in plain English.

Answer (score 0):

On your login page put this:

```
if(Session["loggedin"] != null){
  Response.Redirect("Adminpage.aspx");
}
```

After pressing the login button, and validating the user credentials, do this

```
Session["loggedin"] = true;
```

When the user returns to the login page, there it will check whether the users is already logged in and so redirect back to another page.

**Note:** this will **NOT** work when the browser of your user has cache turned on. I'm affraid you will have to force a refresh of that page, which you can do using a Meta Tag.

Comment: Awww... we were hoping for a re-write of the question before anyone posted an answer :)

Comment: @Tony : What can i say: "we have a site for that ? " http://english.stackexchange.com/