# Logout in c# not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am having below code for logout. when It gets log out but when back is pressed it should not go to previously visited page but it does.

//when login

```
if (txtPassword.Text == password)
                {
                    Session["Login"] = true;
                    Response.Redirect("AdminControlPanel.aspx");
                }
```

//when logout

```
Session["Login"] = false;
            Session.Abandon();
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
            Response.Redirect("~/index.aspx");
```

//checking on adminpanel.aspx

```
if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (this.Session["Login"]==null || (bool)this.Session["Login"]==false)
                {
                   base.Response.Redirect("~/index.aspx");
                }
            }
```

what is wrong with this?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on it and check the value of Session["Login"].

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686946/asp-net-authentication-login-and-logout-with-browser-back-button

Comment: There's no way you can control how the browser, all the proxies in-between and so far handles a user pressing "back". That's probably why so many logout pages asks the user to then close the browser window. Cache-control may or may not be properly honored by any number of middle-men in the chain, as long as the data was once viewed in the browser, it's potentially in one or more caches along the way and can be resurrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set [Cache-Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcacheability.aspx).

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be there may be problem when you assigning the value to the `session` variable

put a break point in `if (txtPassword.Text == password)` and check 
what happens.

also

```
if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
            {            
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) Session["Login"]))
             {
                  var result = Convert.ToBoolean(Session["Login"]); //put a break point there also and check what values it getting
              }


            }
```

Comment: could you put your code where you assigning the values to the session

Comment: are you using asp.net membership provider?