# Logout on Backward

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want the page to sign out automatically if the user accessed the page from back the button.

below is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Visible = false;  
    try
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TxtLogin.Focus();
            Session["url"] = null;

            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            Response.Expires = -1;
            Session.Abandon();

            if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                Response.Redirect("~\\LoginPage.aspx", false);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception(ex.Message); }
}
```

Its working in IE but not working in firefox how to do for firefox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET authentication login and logout with browser back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686946/asp-net-authentication-login-and-logout-with-browser-back-button)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to.  Firefox, when you press the back button, doesn't re-query the server the way IE does, it just "remembers" the entire state of the page and restores to that.  Note that if the user tries to follow any new links, or do anything that will attempt to hit the server again, then it won't work as the user has been signed out.

Comment: I wonder if turning off caching on the page force FF to "re-query" the server.

Comment: @ShaiCohen That depends on whether or not you're willing to disable caching just to prevent this behavior.  It can dramatically hamper performance, and of course whatever indication you give the browser not to cache anything, it has no obligation to honor that (testing with browsers you expect clients to use is the best you can do).