# Session not expiring after logout

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I am storing username and password in session when user logins. After logout, when I press Back button of browser, it again goes to the home page of the user. I want that the session must expire so that after logout when user presses back button, he get's rediected to the login page.

I have already tried

```
Session.RemoveAll();
Session.Abandon();
Session.Remove("StoreUser");
```

*StoreUser* is the name of the session that contains username and password.

Comment: You can write a method on page Load event of HomePage of user and in that method check that if Session does not exists with value, than Redirect that to Logout page

Comment: you are checking session value at the time of login

Comment: did you use mvc, or webforms and did you use formauth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FormsAuthentication.SignOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx) when your logout button click event , look below code

```
public void LogoutLink_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
  FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
}
```

and see this previous useful discussion : [ASP.NET authentication login and logout with browser back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686946/asp-net-authentication-login-and-logout-with-browser-back-button)

Answer (score 0):

I used `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();`

and on an other place in my webapplication, I have this on my WebForm when the user is logged in:

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" LogoutImageUrl="~/Img/Logout.png" 
    BackColor="Transparent" runat="server" onloggingout="LoginStatus1_LoggingOut" />
```

and this in the code behind:

```
protected void LoginStatus1_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
    u.LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-Membership.UserIsOnlineTimeWindow);
    Membership.UpdateUser(u);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may following link help you - 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/135121/Browser-back-button-issue-after-logout

your session is getting cleared but the cache of your page is getting stored at client side. You have to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

```
## IN Global.asax file you have to clear all the session in Session_end event ##
clear all the session in this event.

     protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Code that runs when a session ends.
// Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
// is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer
// or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

}
```