# How to prevent users to entering into website after logout by pressing back button?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication

In my asp.net application user login is available. After user logged out and if pressed the back button it goes to the previously visited page. I need to control the user to again login to enter into the website. How to solve this problem. I writing code in vb.

Comment: This has been asked a few times before, try to use the search. See for example [ASP.NET authentication login and logout with browser back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686946/asp-net-authentication-login-and-logout-with-browser-back-button).

Answer (score 0):

At log out button_click ,

perform `session.Abondon();`

and Check the session in each page_Load like

```
if(session["userName"]!=null)
{
  //Perform the action
}
else
{
  //Redirect to login page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code on logout click

```
 Session.RemoveAll();
 Session.Abandon();
```

Answer (score 0):

add this logout button

```
Session.Abandon();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this...

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  function preventBack() { window.history.forward(); }
  setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
  window.onunload = function () { null };
</script>
```