# Back Button disable

Tags: asp.net

Hai Friends

I have used lot of codinds to disable the browser (using server side code) back button in mozila firefox 3.2 it is not working.But it is working fine in the Internet Explorer.Pls same the correct solution to solve this problem in mozila firefox3.2 version.say me in detail.

Comment: It's better to place your code here that works/doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling Back button on the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87422/disabling-back-button-on-the-browser)

Answer (score 4):

What's the point of disabling such button? The user can achieve exactly the same functionality with keyboard, context menus, bookmarks, mouse gestures... If your program breaks when the user makes use of his browser's history, you should fix whatever breaks in your code rather than annoying the user by crippling his browser.

## Update

Alright, you've made it clear that you want an answer to your question, not a solution to your problem. Sorry for wasting your time.

The answer is that you cannot disable the browser's back button from the server. The proof is that, if such thing was possible, webmasters from porn, scam and spam sites would do it all the times it so you would not be able to leave their sites. Your only chance is to convince your Firefox users one by one to go to the `View-> Toolbars-> Customize` menu and drag the navigation buttons out of the bar. Alternatively, you can try to make them download and install some sort of malware that does this for them.

Comment: that is transcation page user should not go back.if goes to back button it should redirected to login page

Comment: I don't know how your app is designed but if user goes back he should normally be redirected to the page he failed to complete (or, at least, be prompted about it).

Comment: I WANT TO DISABLE BROWSER BACK BUTTON WITH SERVER SIDE CODE

Comment: i want to do in coding disabling th back button