# My browser's back button should not work after logged out?

Tags: browser, back-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disabling Back button on the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87422/disabling-back-button-on-the-browser)

How to do this in asp.net friends?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87422/disabling-back-button-on-the-browser

Comment: Care to enlighten us about WQOSO?

Comment: @carl "Worst Questions On Stack Overflow"

Comment: Right up there with "How can I trick Google into giving me a higher page rank?"

Comment: ..............            无             ................

Answer (score 3):

If I'm a (prospective) customer of your company and you try to take away functionality of my browser, I will get angry at you and your company. You don't want that to happen.

If your user's logged out and uses the back button to go to a stale URL, detect this (it's simple enough!) and show him a page telling him there's nothing to see there. Better yet, take him to your app's home page or something.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable the back button in a browser without using javascript, and even then javascript could be turned off on clients machine

http://forums.asp.net/t/989339.aspx