# Custom ActionFilter for disabling the BACK button

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Currently working on an ASP.NET MVC 3.0 application and using `FormsAuthentication`.

When the user clicks the Logoff link, it calls the following:

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Works great!

But if the user clicks the BACK button, he gets to see his previous page (although he won’t be able to do anything since the `[Authorize]` attribute is set) and we didn’t want that.

After many searches and posts regarding this subject, I ended up creating a custom ActionFilter called `[NoCache]` which is placed right underneath each `[Authorize]` attribute I have.

The `[NoCache]` attribute looks like this:

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore(); 
    }
}
```

It seems to work but I’m curious to know if this seems like the appropriate approach to use (or not). Are there any known issues I’m not aware of in using this technique?

In addition, I’ve been told that if I had an SSL Certificate then I wouldn’t need to do this but instead, create and set an HTTP Header with `Cache-Control: no-cache` which would, ultimately, make *all* my https pages not cached.

Can anyone confirm this?
If the above is true, then why would I create a custom ActionFilter?

Feel free to share any thoughts or better approaches…

Keep in mind, the ultimate goal is to make sure a user does not see his previous page(s) when clicking the BACK button *after* he’s been signed off (`FormsAuthentication.SignOut();`)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conclusion:

I’ve decided to close this post with the following conclusion…

The PRG Model suggestion (and link) provided by Shawn is great and indeed should be practiced while developing MVC applications.

The pattern makes sure users who hit refresh (F5) are not re-submitting the form/data again. So it is a question of making proper redirect after a form submission.

As for my issue, I wanted to show the login page to the users that did try and hit the back button only **after** they’ve signed off (After FormsAuthentication.SignOut).

The behavior I am looking for is the same as when you logoff a banking web site. You are free to hit the back button but they will display a message letting you know that your session has expired (which in turn, you are forced to login again.)

I haven’t found (or worked on) a solution yet but the custom NoCache Attribute seems to be the way to go.

Once in production, I will have an SSL certificate applied to the protected pages and perhaps, when we get there, I might find a different way to achieve my task **without** the use of the NoCache Attribute.

When and if I do, I will share my findings.

Thanks

Comment: Vince, did you find out more about an effective solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Would using RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", "Home") work for you?  I think it will prevent them returning to the immediately previous page (maybe not all).

Scott Hanselman recommended changing the application design to a [Post/Redirect/Get PRG Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) when a similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/87439/529665).

UPDATE:
A third option is to generate a unique token for every page and invalidate the previous token upon every request.  [Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/961245/529665) to a similar question that even mentions a bank using that methodology.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, didn’t read much on the PRG Model (and I will) but it seems to be more BACK button friendly which is great but not sure how it all fits with what I’m trying to do. Perhaps I’m wrong but my concern is not to be BACK friendly, all I want is the same behavior as when you leave/logoff your banking web site and try the BACK button. It pretty much shows a page explaining that your *session* was ended, showing you a link that brings you back to the login page.

Perhaps it is my lack of understanding with the PRG Model that makes me wonder if it will help me reach my desired result.