# How to enable and disable back button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using VS 2010.

I use two links to go back/forward between pages.

**Code:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1);return false"><img src="Images/back.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#" onclick="history.go(1);return false"><img src="Images/forward1.jpg"/></a>
```

It works well. Now I want to enable and disable the links based on browser history.

How do I do this using JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling Back button on the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87422/disabling-back-button-on-the-browser)

Comment: I'm sure people don't want you playing around with their browser history, especially behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

As anchors are used for clicking, any other dom element also can be clicked. So,It is visually better to implement this functionality without using hyperlinks. Use code similar as below:

```
<p id="back"><img src="back.jpg"></p> 
<p id="forward"><img src="forward.jpg"></p>
```

and event as below:

```
$("#back").click(function(){
  if(!$(this).hasClass('disabled'))   history.go(-1);
  $(this).addClass('disabled');
  $("#forward").removeClass('disabled');
});

$("#forward").click(function(){
   if(!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) history.go(1);
  $(this).addClass('disabled');
  $("#back").removeClass('disabled');
});
```

User required style for `.disabled`.

Comment: OP didn't say anything about jQuery, nor did he tag the question with it.

Comment: @Purmou, Sorry. then, Please, Provide your solution over this.