# Browser's previous or next button control

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to access  browser previous or next button using jQuery.When  i click browser previous button  i want to see alert("yes"); or  any response.is it possible?

Comment: Created a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/LZCj7/show/). Take a look if you still need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It is *(somehow)* possible in HTML5. It does not require jQuery. Use `onpopstate` for that.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onpopstate

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {  
    alert("location: " + document.location);  
};
```

But in order to use `onpopstate`, you will have to use `pushState` first.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/LZCj7/show

PS: it is originally made for AJAX applications.

Alternative method:

```
<body onbeforeunload="return 'This is an alert.'">
```

Comment: When using `onpopstate` and `pushState`, the button behaves differently.