# How can I disable the browser's back button on client machine?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disabling Back button on the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87422/disabling-back-button-on-the-browser)

I want to disable the back button of the user's browser (across all browsers) as I have disabled it in my Application.

Comment: Please explain why you need this? I'm sure there is a better way of doing things.

Comment: @Jleagle so let me know how i can generate an alert/pop-up saying avoid clicking back button before user clicks it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control the browser UI buttons. It would have security issues if you could play around with the Browser UI, so nothing along these lines are possible.

What do you mean you have disabled the back button? Instead of taking this away from the user, why not work with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The user should have control of his or her own history.

You can open links in a new window if they have a particular purpose. If you really wanted you could have a javascript popup to confirm before navigating away from the page.

Comment: I know it man....that i've to generate javascript pop-up still I was looking 4 some other answers..