# Execute JS after a user goes history.go(-1)

Tags: javascript, events, cross-browser

**Scenario**

There's a form, placeholders on several inputs, and a jQuery script that replaces them with `.val()`-based "emulated" placeholder functionality bound to `.focus()` and `.blur()`.

Those handlers also check for an attribute (`data-is-being-submitted="1"`) to know whether they should stop replacing values in those inputs. The attribute is set by `form.submit(...)`, then the form triggers `.focus()` on each of those fields, validates the values, submits.

So the user leaves the page with empty non-required fields, and placeholder functionality interrupted. Not a problem unless the user goes back to the page. The page is loaded from cache and doesn't trigger any cool JS event. Or is it?

What else can I go with besides cloning the form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I detect when a user gets to a page using the back button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134106/can-i-detect-when-a-user-gets-to-a-page-using-the-back-button)