# Header location previous page, start at the bottom

Tags: php, header

I am currently using;

```
header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ;
```

Is there a way of directing to the bottom of this page, as opposed to referring back to the top?

Comment: 1, no, 2 HTTP_REFERER is completely unreliable

Comment: `Location: http://example.com/oldpage.html#anchor_at_bottom_of_page`, but as Dagon said, the referer is UTTERLY unreliable.

Comment: Storing the previous page in a session or using js seems infinitely more up to the task indeed.

Comment: One has to wonder why it still even exists (`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`) and why they came up with it in the first place. BIG QUESTION MARK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't rely on server-side client details. Instead, you can try using JS. See: [Can I detect when a user gets to a page using the back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134106/can-i-detect-when-a-user-gets-to-a-page-using-the-back-button) for more info.

Comment: "shouldn't rely anything client-side" then you say JS, which is completely client side

Comment: " Instead, you can try using JS" still totally contradictory

Comment: The point of the answer is "You shouldn't rely on client-side information on the server side (such as headers)".

Comment: Remove `Instead, you can try using JS` then. I agree with Dagon.

Comment: I've rephrased it. Cheers.