# How to stop someone from going back to previous page?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am working on a my site to allow users to take test so they can see how much they know of a particular subject. I am running into a little problem though. Once a user submits the test for grading, how do I prevent them from going back to the test page? I am on a Mac with Safari running and when I click the back button in my web browser after I submit the test it leaves all of the answers I answered filled out. I want it do this: When a user submits a test and they click the back button in their web browser it redirects them to the main test page.

I am using PHP and MYSQL. I even have the test pages setup so that the user must come from a certain url (I am using HTTP_REFERER) and I have tried other stuff such as sessions but I cannot seem to figure this out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling Back button on the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87422/disabling-back-button-on-the-browser)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961188/disable-browsers-back-button, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780718/how-to-disable-back-button-in-ie-and-firefox, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54539/prevent-use-of-the-back-button-in-ie, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359941/how-to-disable-back-button-navigation-on-certain-pages, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665399/how-do-i-stop-the-back-and-refresh-buttons-from-resubmitting-my-form etc might be relevant reading.

Comment: Don't you use sessions mechanism already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't stop them.

Instead change your application so that it still works even if they go back. You can embed a unique number in a hidden field on the page and if they resubmit the same test twice you can detect it and display an appropriate error message. You should also think about what should happen if they modify the unique number.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want people to **post different answers** once they have already answered, all you have to do is check, in the script that accepts the test for grading, that the user has never submitted the test before. If you don't, a clever student will *always* be able to to circumvent your protection by sending an appropriate request directly to that script.

If you don't want people to **see previous answers** (for instance, if you have two people grade their tests on the same computer), consider using AJAX on the test page to submit the answers and then erase them from the fields. This way, most browsers will not remember the answers and the back button will not un-erase data that was erased by JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the grade page, put the following:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['testcomplete'] = 'yes';
```

Then at the top of each page of the test, put this:

```
session_start()
if ($_SESSION['testcomplete'] == 'yes') {
    header("Location:cheater.php");
}
```

Comment: Every browser on the planet lets the user delete cookies.

Comment: That is true.  They all let you disable javascript as well.

Comment: In short : server-side data integrity can never be guaranteed through client-side techniques.

Comment: Excuse me but, Why don't you put an extra column on your database that defaults to 0 and then updated to 1 once its been pulled to the page, So you only allow to query for 0 value rows? if row = 1 then print warning...

Answer (score 1):

You could simulate there being no page to go back to.  From one page, generate each test page using jQuery, and provide no way to go back, only forward.  The back button would take them to the page before they ever launched the test, and you could allow them to launch the test again and generate the right part where they should be.  This would be pretty easy, if you haven't gone too far in development the current way.

Answer (score 0):

You could run javascript that clears out all the answers. You might also just allow one submission so that subsequent submissions don't get processed. HTTP_REFERER is usually sent, but can be spoofed and forged by an altered browser.

Comment: Another thing you might look at is using headers/meta tags to keep the page from caching - using headers like

    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">

More information could be retrieved from [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067)

Answer (score 0):

On the top of the script POST-ing the answers, do a check whether you have the test results in the database for the current user for this test. If you do, redirect to results.

```
if(get_test_results($user)){
   $test_url = get_test_url($user);
   header( "Location: $test_url" ) ;
}
```

Disabling the back button is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem making an online examination myself

what I did is

- I provided a session variable such that if the user pastes the previous page's URL in the address bar then on loading the page the page is automatically forwards to the next desired page. Whether the page whose URL was mentioned is the being visited the first time or being revisited is determined by the value of the session variable
- If the user instead of loading the page does a go back via the browser button the it automatically redirects to the next page in history as :

> javascript:window.history.forward(1);

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/buttons/article.php/3478911/Disabling-the-Back-Button.htm you should be able to do it in javascript.