# How can I prevent the user to go back to my shop checkout with the "back" button of the browser?

Tags: php

**checkout.php:**

```
<form action="success.php" method="post">
    <input name="firstname">
    <button type="submit">Order now</button>
</form>
```

**success.php:**

```
if ( !empty($_POST)) {
  echo "Hello ".$_POST['name'].". Your order was successful"
}
```

After ordering my customer gets to the `success.php` page. I want to prevent now that by clicking on the "back button" of the browser the user gets back to the checkout.php. I wish he would go to my index.php. Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460440/how-to-stop-someone-from-going-back-to-previous-page

Comment: store session in your success.php, then check if is session set in your previous page and if is, redirect to index.php, clear session after new order

Comment: *"Is this possible?"* - Yes it is possible and there are many scripts out there. If you haven't been looking, then look. If you didn't find anything that fits the bill, then keep looking or post what you tried to work with and may have failed you.

Comment: @ka_lin and Pepo_rasta Very good advices, thank you very much. I wouldn't have thought of this!

Comment: @Maurize That's a JS solution. If a user disables JS, that method will be of no use to them.

Comment: @Fred-ii- my mistake. missed the tag.