# Meta Tag refresh not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cross-browser

Below is my code .. In IE and Firefox it works fine .. i.e after 10seconds it gets redirected to www.google.com .. but the same code doesn't work in Chrome

```
<html>  
<head>
<title>App- Log In</title>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=http://www.google.com">

<script language="JavaScript">
      function noBack(){window.history.forward()}
      noBack();
      window.onload=noBack;
      window.onpageshow=function(evt){if(evt.persisted)noBack()}
      window.onunload=function(){void(0)}
</script>   

</head>

  <body>
Testing
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure about this one.. but have you tried removing the space between 10; and url=http://...?

Comment: `<html style="display: block; ">` is not valid HTML code

Comment: removed that style . .. even then the same problem

Comment: Is the server sending an actual `Refresh` HTTP header?  That should override the in page one.

Comment: Could you explain what's going on in the first `script` tag? I don't get it. Is it suppose to prevent navigating back using the browser history?

Comment: yes Per you are right .. its a script to prevent back navigation

Comment: It's not working for me in Chrome or IE9. I can navigate back.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
window.history.forward()
```

Whenever this line has executed, the meta-refresh disables in Chrome.

My recommendation would be not to try to disable the back button since it isn't working reliably, and from what I gather [it can't be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54539/prevent-use-of-the-back-button-in-ie).

Comment: Correct Per .. If i remove the back button navigation script .. it works fine even in chrome .. But i can't ignore that script ..