# how can I stop the functionality of the BACK browser button?

Tags: forms, web, webbrowser-control, back-button, survey

I have a survey created with formsite, but I want the users to not be able to go back and change the answer to a question after they have answered it...
so I had the idea of somehow blocking the Back browser button... is this possible?
thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Use of the Back Button (in IE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54539/prevent-use-of-the-back-button-in-ie)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable browser's back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961188/disable-browsers-back-button)

Comment: not the same thing..   I am trying to use this functionality on this https://fs30.formsite.com/Websurvey/form3/form_login.html    try to type TEST and TEST in the login form, and then hit back: it works.... but i want uesrs to not be able to go back